Why Is Intellesense & Colour Formatting Not Working In Some Files In VS
Intellisense and text colour formatting is not working in some files in my VS solution (VS 2022):

Everything is working in others, but not in the classes within the models folder.
Also when I try and reference these classes in other classes, they cannot be found by the compiler.
Why would this be happening?

This was happening because I tried to save some time and copied some cshtml files into my models folder and then renamed them changing the file type to C#. The issue was that the build action in the file properties did not change.

In order to resolve the issue, the build action needed to be changed to "C# compiler"

This results in colour formatting and intellisense being restored and the class being accessible for reference from other classes.

